# Kafka to Kafka mirroring with sampling

Tags: apache-kafka

Any idea how to make kafka-to-kafka mirroring but with a sampling (for example only 10% of the messages)?

Comment: In your consumer you can just ignore some of the messages.

Comment: Unless you elaborate what problem you face and are trying to solve, I'd mark it to be closed.

Comment: Also you can use the seek() method on the KafkaConsumer to skip to a particular message offset.

Comment: we have Kafka servers on production env with massive data in each topic, I want to sample it for our Kafka servers on dev, and wondering what is the best way to do it... @JacekLaskowski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `MirrorMakerMessageHandler` (which is configured by `message.handler` parameter):

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/MirrorMaker.scala#L430

The handler itself would need to make a decision whether to forward a message. A simple implementation would be just a counter of messages received, and forwarding if `0 == counter % 10`.

However this handler is invoked for every message received, so it means that you'd be receiving all of messages & throwing away 90% of them.

---

The alternative is to modify main loop, where the mirror maker consumer receives the message, and forwards it to producers (that send the message to mirror cluster) is here

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/MirrorMaker.scala#L428

You would need to modify the consumer part to either-or:

- forward only N-th (10th) message/offset
- seek to only N-th message in log

I prefer the former idea, as in case of multiple MM instances in the same consumer group, you would still get reasonable behaviour. Second choice would demand more work from you to handle reassignments.

Also, telling which message is from 10% is non-trivial, I just assumed that it's every 10th message received.